# How can I remove space between label?

Tags: python, label, qt5, space, pythonqt

I want to remove the space between labels.
Range number of labels is 1 to 5 and is used in loop ( text got from db )

I Used varios option but everythoing failed
(.setAlignment/.setMargin~~~~)

And I googled many documents, but I could not find any solution.

How Can I Do ?

[image: result picture of code... click here]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # self.setGeometry(-1700, -300, 1500, 800)
        self.setGeometry(  500, 200, 500, 200)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tableWidget.resize(1000, 1000)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        # self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        
        column_labels = ["column1", "column2"]
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(column_labels)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("test1"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("63,900"))

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        QFont('Arial', 10)
        label1 = QLabel("             ")
        label1.setFont(QFont('Arial', 20))
        label1.resize(200, 100)
        label1.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : red; color : black;}")

        label2 = QLabel("            ")
        label2.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : blue; color : blue; padding:0}")
        
        label3 = QLabel("            ")
        label3.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : lightgreen; color : blue; padding:0}")
        
        
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(label1)
        layout.addWidget(label2)
        layout.addWidget(label3)
        layout.addStretch(1)

        self.title = QLabel("97%")
        # self.title.setMargin(0)

        f = QFrame()
        f.setLayout(layout)
        f.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(0, 1, f )
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 300)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywindow = MyWindow()
    mywindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the spacing of the labels through setSpacing(0). This code works:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500, 200, 500, 200)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tableWidget.resize(1000, 1000)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        
        column_labels = ["column1", "column2"]
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(column_labels)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("test1"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("63,900"))

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)  # Set spacing to zero to remove space between labels

        label1 = QLabel("             ")
        label1.setFont(QFont('Arial', 20))
        label1.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : red; color : black;}")
        layout.addWidget(label1)

        label2 = QLabel("            ")
        label2.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : blue; color : blue;}")
        layout.addWidget(label2)
        
        label3 = QLabel("            ")
        label3.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : lightgreen; color : blue;}")
        layout.addWidget(label3)

        f = QFrame()
        f.setLayout(layout)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(0, 1, f)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 300)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywindow = MyWindow()
    mywindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]